# How to make system choose port no for me in socket programming?

Tags: sockets, port

How to make system choose port no  for me on the connect() call in c below is my code where i have used 5000 as port no the problem is every time i have to keep on changing the port no because it is throwing exception as ?

listen: Address already in use

How to get rid of this i want to fix the port no without making change in future is it possible?

```
int main(void)
{
    int sockfd = 0,n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
            return 1;
        }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);  //how to skip Address already in use?

    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: You're not using `listen` in this code, I don't see how it could produce that error.

Comment: You probably just need to use the `SO_REUSEADDR` option when binding the port on the server. That will allow you to reuse the same port when you restart the server.

Comment: How are you closing the socket? If you aren't closing it properly then the address will often remain in use for for a while

Comment: @Barmar sir can you please put it in code because i couldn't figure out how to use so_REUSEADDR plz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in [IANA Port number Listing](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), pick the which is not assigned or registered a prior. In your case port number `5000` is a TCP port already registered and used for `commplex-main`.

Note: Do not choose ports between `0 - 1023` as they are used by system processes.

Comment: What's the chance that he's running a `complex-main` server on the system? He says he has to keep changing the port, it's probably the standard `SO_REUSEADDR` problem.

Comment: @Barmar Likely what you said should be correct. rm my answer.